# Difference between NSEntityDescription creation methods

Tags: ios, core-data, creation, nsentitydescription

What is the difference, in terms of outcome, between the 2 following methods:

```
+ (id)insertNewObjectForEntityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;

+ (NSEntityDescription *)entityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
```

When should I use each one of them?

Answer (score 4):

`insertNewObjectForEntityForName` creates an instance of the entity and adds it to the context. The context is now dirty and needs to be saved. The returned instance is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

`entityForName` returns the `NSEntityDescription` instance which describes the entity, what attributes and relationships it has, how they are constructed. The context is not modified in any way.

Answer (score 1):

`insertNewObjectForEntityForName:...` returns `NSManangedObject` object which is same as below code.

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel =
        [[context persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectModel];
NSEntityDescription *entity =
        [[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:entityName];
NSManagedObject *newObject = [[NSManagedObject alloc]
            initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
return newObject;
```

`entityForName:..` returns `NSEntityDescription` object which is same as below code.

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[context persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectModel]; 
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:entityName]; 
return entity;
```

Answer (score 0):

The id variable is a data type that represents an object’s address. Because it’s just an address, id can be any object, and because its type is a pointer,you don’t need to include the * symbol

```
+ (id)insertNewObjectForEntityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
```

As the * symbol signifies a pointer to a specific type.

```
+ (NSEntityDescription *)entityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
```